# PHP checkbox from Database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

The problem is that I can change the value of 'nestor' from true to false, but I cannot change it from false to true. I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Here is my code

```
<div>
    Nestor is required: 
<input type="checkbox" name="nestor" <?= ($project_list['Project_list']['nestor'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '') ?>>
    <?php
    // Het bijwerken van nestor in de database
    $project_list['Project_list']['nestor'] = ($_POST['nestor'] ?? 0);
    $db->update($project_list);
    ?>
</div>
```

PHP checkbox from Database

Comment: Only checked boxes get sent to the server. So use `isset($_POST['nestor'])` to tell whether the box is checked.

Comment: Side note, you can shorten the if statement you use in your code by using a ternary. e.g `<?= $project_list['Project_list']['nestor'] ? 'checked' : '' ?>` where the value before the `:` is the value if the expression is true, and the value after is if it is false. You don't need to compare `== 1` because 1 is truthy, so the expression `if(1)` will execute because it is true